# An algorithm to turn descending order into ascending order, but why correct?

Tags: sorting

I wonder why does this algorithm below work well? Many appreciates!

## Task:

Suppose all elements in an array with length $n = 2^m$ are in descending order: $a_1 > a_2 > ... > a_n$, we need to turn them into ascending order.

## Algorithm:

For each step from $1$ to $m$:

1. Swap each adjacent (odd index, even index) pair into ascending order, so that:
   $a_1 \le a_2, a_3 \le a_4, ... , a_{n-1} \le a_n$
2. Move all elements with odd index to the front of those
   with even index, so $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, ..., a_{n - 1}, a_n$ turns to : $a_1, a_3, ..., a_{n - 1}, a_2, a_4, ..., a_n$

## Example:

Sort result after each step with $n = 8$:

[0] 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
[1] 7 5 3 1 8 6 4 2
[2] 5 1 6 2 7 3 8 4
[3] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

## Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int *arr, int i, int j)
{
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}

void magic_sort(int *arr, int *result, int n)
{
    int half = n >> 1;
    int i;

    /* Swap adjacent (odd index, even index) pair into ascending order */
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])swap(arr, i, i + 1);
    }

    /* Move all elements with odd index to front half */
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        result[(i + 1) / 2] = arr[i];
    }

    /* Move all elements with even index to tail half */
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        result[half + i / 2] = arr[i];
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = result[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int m = 3;
    int n = 1 << m;
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(*arr) * (n + 1));
    int *result = (int *)malloc(sizeof(*arr) * (n + 1));
    int step, i;

    printf("[%d] ", 0);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = n + 1 - i;

        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (step = 0; step < m; step++)
    {
        magic_sort(arr, result, n);

        printf("[%d] ", step + 1);

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    free(arr);
    free(result);

    return 0;
}
```